# How to simulate polymorphism in typescript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, polymorphism

I am trying to simulate the OOP concept in typescript. I am from a Java background. The problem I am facing is, I am trying to create a Board game. I have Celltypes like Hotel,Jail,Treasure and so on. They all have common attribute called amount of type number. So I created an interface called CellType and implemented it to the individual classes mentioned above(Hotel,Treasure so on)
There is a class called Board where I want to initialise and declare an array of predefined celltypes. Something like this :

> var cell[:CellType];        //declaration 
>   
> Hotel = new Hotel(200);
>       cell = [Hotel1,Treasure1,Jail1,Hotel2..]   //initialization

In java we can do :

```
interface CellType{ public integer amount};
class Hotel implements CellType;
class Jail implements Celltype;
// in main class
ArrayList<CellType> cellTypes = new ArrayList<CellType>;
Hotel Taj = new Hotel();
cellTypes.add(Taj);
Jail jail = new Jail();
cellTypes.add(jail);
```

So, how can I declare an array of multiple child classes that are inheriting the same superclass the way we do it in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface/classes:

```
interface CellType { amount: number };

class Hotel implements CellType { 
  // This concise syntax creates the public property
  // and assigns to it the value passed into the
  // constructor
  constructor(public amount: number) { }
}

class Jail implements CellType {
  constructor(public amount: number) { }
}
```

Usage:

```
let cellTypes: Array<CellType> = []; // Or let cellTypes: CellType[] = [];

let taj = new Hotel(100);
cellTypes.push(taj);
let jail = new Jail(200);
cellTypes.push(jail);
```

You can be more concise like this:

```
let cellTypes: Array<CellType> = [new Hotel(100), new Jail(200)];
```

Comment: "thank you's" are nice, but accepting answers is nicer!